# Can I mix SAS and SATA2 drives on one controller?

Tags: hardware-raid, sata, sas

I've read [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14711327&#14711327) that I can't mix SAS and SATA2 drives on the same controller - is that *really* true? I understand I shouldn't mix on the same channel, but the same card!?

For example, when I plug my 6-drive backplane (IBM x3650-7979) via [SFF-8087 cable](http://www.pcicase.co.uk/index.php?pag=cms&id=177&p=faq.html) connector into an [Adaptec 2405](http://www.adaptec.com/de-de/products/controllers/hardware/sas/entry/sas-2405/). Spinning 2 SAS drives (Ch.1), and 4 SATA2 drives (Ch.2+3) - Would it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. This works fine and is not an uncommon arrangement. You may want to look into using [nearline or midline SAS drives](https://serverfault.com/questions/301567/sas-or-sata-for-3-tb-drives) instead of SATA for future installations, though. These days, there are fewer reasons to use SATA disks given the high-capacity SAS options available.

See: [SAS or SATA for 3 TB drives?](https://serverfault.com/questions/301567/sas-or-sata-for-3-tb-drives)

Comment: Just a short follow up: the Adaptec is a "4 channel" raid card, that means 4 raid channels (as I assumed above), right. It can handle these 6 disks, can it?

Comment: The Adaptec is a 4-port card (4-lane SAS SFF-8088 connector). It can only accommodate 4 disks. You can use a SAS expander or a server/enclosure with a SAS expander to connect more disks. But as is, you're limited to 4 disks.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer indicates that the built-in backplane IBM 44W3110 (or similar) then works as an expander, as the connector seems to be the 4-lane one, and the build-in raid card ServeRaid 8k-l I'm replacing doesn't seem as capable as the newer Adaptec 2405. -- Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't know the difference between the controllers. How many ports/drive slots does the server have available? How many connectors are on the backplane?

Comment: I think I've researched it myself. There's only one SFF x4 connector, but the backplane is sometimes also referred to by IBM as an Expander etc., has a CPU and stuff, and seems to act as an Expander. These systems have 6 disk slots... So thanks, ewwhite.